# Cannot read property of undefined when trying to access a method from another method

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to populate an array from an axios request. The result of the axios request is retrieved by a parent component and its child component populates the table with the data.

Here is what I've done so far :

```
<script>
    import NewSpecification from "../components/NewSpecification";
    import SpecificationTable from "../components/SpecificationTable";
    export default {
        name: "Specifications",
        components:{NewSpecification,SpecificationTable},
        props: [
            'ingredients',
            'dishes',
            'nutritionalProperties',
            'mealPlan'
        ],
        data(){
            return{
                showNewSpecification: false,
                specifications: []
            }
        },
        watch:{
            mealPlan:function(){
                this.specifications = this.getSpecifications();
            }
        },
        methods:{
            getSpecifications(){
                var specifications = [];

                var restrictedIngredients = this.mealPlan.restricted_ingredients;
                restrictedIngredients.forEach(function(item){
                    specifications.push({
                        type: "Ingredient",
                        item: item.name,
                        meals: this.getStringMeals(item.pivot.breakfast,item.pivot.snack1,item.pivot.lunch,item.pivot.snack2,item.pivot.dinner)
                    })
                });

                var restrictedDishes = this.mealPlan.restricted_dishes;
                restrictedDishes.forEach(function(item){
                    specifications.push({
                        type: "Dish",
                        item: item.name,
                        meals: this.getStringMeals(item.pivot.breakfast,item.pivot.snack1,item.pivot.lunch,item.pivot.snack2,item.pivot.dinner)
                    })
                });

                var restrictedNutritionalProperties = this.mealPlan.restricted_nutritional_properties;
                restrictedNutritionalProperties.forEach(function(item){
                    specifications.push({
                        type: "Dish",
                        item: item.name,
                        meals: {
                            breakfast: item.pivot.breakfast,
                            snack1: item.pivot.snack1,
                            lunch: item.pivot.lunch,
                            snack2: item.pivot.snack2,
                            dinner: item.pivot.dinner
                        }
                    })
                });

                return specifications;
            },

            getStringMeals(breakfast,snack1,lunch,snack2,dinner){
                return (breakfast ? 'Breakfast, ' : '') + (snack1 ? 'Snack 1, ' : '') + (lunch ? 'Lunch, ' : '') + (snack2 ? 'Snack 2, ' : '') + (dinner ? 'Dinner, ' : '')
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

However, an error is thrown when I call the method "getStringMeals", and I don't have a clue why I can't access this method from the method getSpecifications().

This is the error thrown in the console:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getStringMeals' of undefined

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript `this` acts differently than other languages like Java. 
Please read [this mdn page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

When you use `this` inside `forEach`, it refers to forEach context.

To answer your question, you can store this in a variable:

```
var self = this;
restrictedDishes.forEach(function(item){
    specifications.push({
        type: "Dish",
        item: item.name,
        meals: self.getStringMeals(item.pivot.breakfast,item.pivot.snack1,item.pivot.lunch,item.pivot.snack2,item.pivot.dinner)
    })});
```

Or use fat arrow syntax:

```
restrictedIngredients.forEach((obj) => {
   specifications.push({
       type: "Ingredient",
       item: item.name,
       meals: this.getStringMeals(item.pivot.breakfast,item.pivot.snack1,item.pivot.lunch,item.pivot.snack2,item.pivot.dinner)
       })});
```

Comment: Worked perfectly ! Thanks for your help and make me understand why it didn't work !

Answer (score 1):

Use the arrow function for forEach as shown below.

```
restrictedIngredients.forEach((obj) => {
                    specifications.push({
                        type: "Ingredient",
                        item: item.name,
                        meals: this.getStringMeals(item.pivot.breakfast,item.pivot.snack1,item.pivot.lunch,item.pivot.snack2,item.pivot.dinner)
                    })
                })
```